# Extracting multiple separate pages from a pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, batch-processing, acrobat

I have a 1590 page pdf and I'm looking to extract every 15th page starting with page 8.

I'm very inexperienced in `javascript`, how would I do something like this?

This is my code so far but I get an error.

`this.extractPages(5, 8, 23, 38, 53, 68, 83 ,98, 113, 128, 143, 158, 173, 188, 203, 218, 233, 248, 263, 278, 293, 308, 323, 338, 353, 368, 383, 398, 413, 428, 443, 458, 473, 488, 503, 518, 533, 548, 563, 578, 593, 608, 623, 638, 653, 668, 683, 698, 713, 728, 743, 758, 773, 788, 803, 818, 833, 848, 863, 878, 893, 908, 923, 938, 953, 968, 983, 998, 1013, 1028, 1043, 1058, 1073, 1088, 1103, 1118, 1133, 1148, 1163, 1178, 1193, 1208, 1223, 1238, 1253, 1268, 1283, 1298, 1313, 1328, 1343, 1358, 1373, 1388, 1403, 1418, 1433, 1448, 1463, 1478, 1493, 1508, 1523, 1538, 1553, 1568, 1583,  "TestExtract1.pdf")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following in the Acrobat JS console with the PDF open. 
Since it counts pages starting at `0` you need to start with `7`, not `8`.

If you set the start page & interval as variables you can edit and reuse the script more easily.

```
var start=7;
var interval=15;

for (var i=start; i<this.numPages; i+=interval) {     
      if(i<=this.numPages){
       console.println(i)
       this.extractPages(i); 
      }
      else {
        console.println("pg does not exist at " + i);
      }      
 }
```

This opens each extracted page as a separate file, which you then have to rename and save to your desired location. Messed around w/that tutorial to rename & save files, but it doesn't work as explained anymore. Also not sure if the `if/else` check is necessary, but not sure what'd happen if adding 15pgs exceeds the length & it tries to extract a non-existent page.

This should be enough to get you the pages you need. Will edit if I get the naming & saving part working. Adobe JS documentation is kind of a mess and this console is awful ...

Comment: I tried pasting this into the console but nothing runs, it justs adds more lines when I hit enter.

Comment: You apparently have to select all the lines & hit "Shift" and "Enter" to run it. Note: half the time I did that, it deletes the code and you have to copy/paste it again. Like I said, the console is awful ... Good luck!

Comment: Perfect, it's worth noting that it has to be Shift + NumPad Enter not regular return.